# Autoescape Django Form Errors

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

So I have a model like this:

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a <b>username</b>.'})
```

And in my template file:

```
{% if registration_form.username.errors %}<li>{{ registration_form.username.errors|escape }}</li>{% endif %}
```

But it displays like so:

```
Please enter a <b>username</b>.
```

No matter what I try I can't turn autoescape off. I've tried `{% autoescape off %}{% endautoescape %}` tags, as well as `|safe|escape`.

I've read the documentation and countless websites regarding this issue but nothing I try has any effect.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
username = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a <b>username</b>.'})
```

Try [mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe):

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': mark_safe('Please enter a <b>username</b>.')})
```